# Trying to build My UE5 C++ Project in Visual Studio Code - it doesn't build in Visual Studio Code but builds in Visual Studio 2019 and UE Live Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The project I'm working on in Visual Studio Code builds fine when you use the Live Code from The Unreal Editor but if you try to build from Visual Studio you get this in the terminal...

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

I'm assuming it is choking on the space in C:\Program Files    (however that is a standard space in that Windows created directory so I can't change it without breaking links for countless other files in that directory). As well when you build from Unreal it doesn't choke on that space - so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to "ignore" the spaces. And since Visual Studio 2019 has no issues building that project - it must have some setting that is also ignoring the spaces. Thanks in advance.

(it doesn't seem to fail - it just seems to soft lock? the "thinking spinner" just keeps spinning and it never seems to complete the build task).

I brought the same project into Visual Studio 2019 and it builds fine, however I can't get Unreal's Live Code to link with 2019 so I'm just trying to get this working in Visual Studio Code since Live Code works great with it.

Comment: Try to add double quotes to the file path: `"C:\Program Files..."`

Comment: I know its something like that - however I don't even know what path its trying to find. That's all the info I can see. I moved the project and Visual Studio Code into my D drive - so that I could ensure it wasn't going into the C: Program Files flow - but that didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Ya, I am not so familiar with UE5, but I just suggest solution based on my experience, I think you need C:\Program Files because it's where UE5 located, so you may try to install UE5 at D, again maybe I'm wrong, but you may try